# XML parsing: line 1, character 23, illegal name character

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Does anybody know why this XML text throws illegal name character error in SQL Server 2008?

```
'<cs><c a="2" b="CITY & STATE TX" c="CITY & STATE TX"/></cs>'
```

Exception message is

```
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XML parsing: line 1, character 23, illegal name character
```

Following is the query used for parse this xml

```
DECLARE @CaptionsDescriptions XML = '<cs><c a="2" b="CITY & STATE TX" c="CITY & STATE TX"/></cs>'

DECLARE @DocHandle int  
DECLARE @CaptionsDescriptionsTable TABLE  
(  
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),  
 languageID INT,  
 Caption  VARCHAR(50),  
 Description VARCHAR(2000)  
)  

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT,@CaptionsDescriptions    
INSERT INTO @CaptionsDescriptionsTable SELECT a,b,c  
 FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle,'cs/c')   
 WITH (  
    a int, -- language id  
    b varchar(50), -- caption  
    c varchar(2000) -- description  
   )  

-- remove document handler  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly where the invalid character is. Also, why tag with C#?

Comment: Nice example to show why people should not form xml manually.

Comment: What if you try and cast the string as SqlString? Will it convert the & to &amp; automatically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `&` is a reserved/special character in XML. It should be `&amp;`

I'll even add that `XML parsing: line 1, character 23, illegal name character` is quite clear **if** you know that SQL counts from 1: then the 23rd character is the `&`.

Comment: It's not that clear unless you know that in XML syntax `&` can only be followed by '#' or a name... But it's always difficult to design error messages that mean something to people who don't know the rules.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change **&** to `&amp;`

Do read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

put your values under cdata cover like this

```
DECLARE @CaptionsDescriptions XML = '<cs><c a="2" b="<![CDATA[CITY & STATE TX]>" c="CITY & STATE TX"/></cs>'
```